# Do turbo-charged engines have stronger internals?

Tags: engine-theory, forced-induction

Of course this question applies to engines that come from the factory turbo charged. But to rephrase the question in a better way, do the internals of an engine designed to handle boost need to be "stronger" than the internals of a naturally aspirated engine? If so, other than internals what else is designed in consideration for the turbo-charger application? And finally are engines with an aftermarket forced induction pushing the limits of the internals even if the tune of the engine was reasonable?

Comment: This is a broad question. Different manufacturers can and do design/build engines differently. Plus you've got too much going on (too many questions). Please narrow your focus or I will have to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the internals of an engine designed to handle boost need to be "stronger" than the internals of a naturally aspirated engine?

*In short, **maybe**.*

Because there are at least two factors at play here:

- Each load-bearing component has an inherent [factor of safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_of_safety) built into it, so they can tolerate more than what they are designed for.

  It is difficult to assign a single value for this, since the factors of safety will vary across different engine components, designs and manufacturers.
- In-cylinder pressures will be higher, so the mechanical loads endured by the cylinder liners, crank pins, connecting rods, crankshaft, gasket, etc. will be greater, so there will be a limit to how much boost can be run before mechanical failure becomes a real possibility.

  Again, this limit will vary across different engine components, designs and manufacturers, and the integrity of the engine will only be as strong as the weakest component.

---

> What else is designed in consideration for the turbo-charger application?

In most gasoline engines, compression ratio needs to be lowered in order to safely run a boosted setup. There are many means to achieve this, probably best left for another Q&A.

---

> Are engines with an aftermarket forced induction pushing the limits of the internals even if the tune of the engine was reasonable?

A boosted engine will run closer to the mechanical limit because of higher in-cylinder pressures. It doesn't necessarily mean that the internals will fail sooner though, as long as the engine operates within its mechanical limits.

Comment: Jus to add one point to Zaid's answer, when you're talking about factory turbo'd cars, the turbos are (generally) quite small, low-boost, setups. This is again because of the manufacturers' biggest concern being cost/profit. They can spend a couple hundred dollars slapping a "turbo" model together and tack $10k on the sticker and many people will buy it. So - generally - a manufacturer will try to keep things as cheap as possible which means using as many of the same parts as possible.